# Boxfuse silently ignores elastic IP parameter during run

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudcaptain

On AWS I have elastic IP allocated, lets say `66.66.66.66`, in case I redeploy my EC2 instance using boxfuse, I want to reassing elastic IP mentoined above with new EC2 instance created by boxfuse, Im using following command:

```
boxfuse run -env=prod -elasticip=66.66.66.66 [other params...]
```

But its not working as I expect, new EC2 instance allocates new, very different address and I have to reallocate it manually. What is wrong with my command? There is no warnings or errors in console, for me it seems like boxfuse silently ignores this parameter. My boxfuse util looks like follows:

```
$ boxfuse -v
Boxfuse client v.1.33.0.1460
Copyright 2018 Boxfuse GmbH. All rights reserved.


VirtualBox : 6.0.10_RPMFusionr132055
JVM        : 1.8.0_74 (Oracle Corporation)
Host IP    : 172.18.0.1 (2a:e1:4c:88:23:9e)
OS         : Linux 5.2.7-100.fc29.x86_64 amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, my generation script had an issue, and was generating EC2 application of type `load-balanced` instead of `single-instance`, this was the reason it was not working.

So in my opinion this is still an issue of boxfuse, boxfuse should stdout, at least warning that `-elasticip` is not applicable to applications with type different than `single-instance`.